# Responsive not working

Tags: css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to make a web site where I am trying with html and css. But the problem is how to make a **responsive site**. when I try never get any output like responsive. Here I have tried this still I am not get proper response site.

```
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <style>
        @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width :1024px) 
        {
            #wrapper
            {
                background-color:#000;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<style>
        @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width :1024px) 
        {
            #wrapper
            {
                background-color:#000!important;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

or, this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    // Add your css here
    #wrapper
    {
         background-color:#000!important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The style tag is always put under the "head" section, unless you're using the "scoped" attribute, wherein you can define styles within the body itself.

Comment: no, there are two files css separate file. just i post like inline style by the way html and css separate files

Comment: Hmm... that's strange, it works perfectly on my browser.

Comment: may be my browser problem?? i check it with FF also

Answer (score 0):

You can use following rule for responsive css design :-

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    // Add your css here
    #wrapper
    {
         background-color:#000;
    }
}
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your current meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

My current working meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Maybe "0" end of initial-scale is getting problem.